# PBKDF2 and C# questions

Tags: c#, security, hash, pbkdf2

i am trying to understand this key derivation function and i have some questions

1) in C#, seems that Rfc2898DeriveBytes implement it with SHA1, but i want to try to use SHA512 for more security. How can i use SHA512 for PBKDF2 in C#?

2) I read about hash collision but i dont understand it yet, so whats the proper length of salt and hash to have decent security?

Comment: What research have you done that shows doing SHA512 will give you better security when doing a Key derivation function over SHA1? All weaknesses that apply to SHA1 vs SHA512 do not apply to the way it is being used here.

Comment: ohh sorry i did not any research, but SHA1 use 20 byte and SHA512 uses 64, PBKDF2 have the length u decide but i readed that u cant choose a random length because you have to take your Salt length in consideration because there is something called collisions.. So i am a little confused here. Maybe is not more secure SHA512 but have more bytes as output, i think this force you to use larger PBKDF2 length and that seems more secure for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in C#, seems that Rfc2898DeriveBytes implement it with SHA1, but i want to try to use SHA512 for more security. How can i use SHA512 for PBKDF2 in C#?

`Rfc2898DeriveBytes` now accepts a `HashAlgorithmName` in the constructor as of .NET Framework 4.7.2.

For older versions of .NET:

This is unfortunately just a limit of the implementation of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, it does not let you specify the hash function. SHA512 is probably overkill, and many would argue that SHA1 is still probably safe to use. However many people *do* use SHA256. You would have to find another implementation. Microsoft made another library called [CLR Security](https://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/) that extends the System.Security.Cryptography namespace.

One of the things that it does do is use Microsoft's CNG API. It does offer an implementation of PBKDF2 that supports specifying the hash function, including SHA512. You can [find it on Codeplex](https://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Security.Cryptography/src/BCryptPBKDF2.cs). The only downside to this is, it won't run on XP or Server 2003 since CNG was introduced in Windows Vista / Server 2008.

> I read about hash collision but i dont understand it yet, so whats the proper length of salt and hash to have decent security?

Your salt should be fairly long. A good example might be the salt could be the same size as the output of the hash function, so with SHA512 you would use a 64 byte salt. Generally your salt should be a big enough value that it cannot easily be brute forced. It should also be random and not some "user" data, like the username.

Comment: Lets say i use default C# PBKDF2 implementation with SHA1 and i decided to use a 64 bytes salt with 128 bytes output, the algorithm uses SHA1 that is 20 bytes output for my 64 bytes salt... Is this correct? Could i use an already derived salt with SHA512 as salt? this improve security?

Comment: @Ralstlin I would give this blog post a read, it will clear up a lot of questions, I think: http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/